# Is it correct to do stats in log transformed metabolomics data?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, logarithm

I have a dataset from targeted metabolomics analysis, the units I am working with are ng/ml[creatinine] (I use creatinine concentration to normalize the data since the samples are urine and can have different hydration levels).

I am comparing the concentration of x metabolite in healthy vs sick patients.

The distribution is skewed, so I log-transformed it so that it could meet normality assumptions. However, I keep receiving feedback about how it is better to "reduce manipulation of the data" and avoid log-transforming it.

From literature, it seems like what I am doing is correct, but I would like some input from more experienced people.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing about metabolomics my answer is yes. Log-transformed data can be tested statistically.

But, I would rather recommend you to read the Lo and Andrews paper (2015): To transform or not to transform: using generalized linear mixed models to analyse reaction time data

Maybe you would prefer to test your model using another family (distribution), depending on the nature of your data and the skewness you may test the goodness of fit (GOF) for other distributions. Anyhow, I would advice you to test your data both ways (gaussian-log and the family you selected from the GOF tests) since the results should in principle not differ.